# Apache Spark Dataset convert

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My aim is to combine 2 tables.
How can I do that in Java?

I am getting error while using this code.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("SQL").master("local").getOrCreate();
        final Properties cp = new Properties();
        cp.put("user", "root");
        cp.put("password", "1234");

        Dataset<Row> studentData = sparkSession.read().jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dd", "student", cp);
        Dataset<Row> schoolData = sparkSession.read().jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dd", "school", cp);

        Dataset<Ogrenci> studentDS = studentData.as(Encoders.bean(Ogrenci.class));
        Dataset<Okul> schoolDS = schoolData.as(Encoders.bean(Okul.class));


        Dataset<Row> resultDS = studentDS.joinWith(schoolDS, studentData.col("schoolId") == schoolDS.col("id")).drop("schoolId"); ??

        resultDS.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: this line error Dataset<Row> resultDS = studentDS.joinWith(schoolDS, studentData.col("schoolId") == schoolDS.col("id")).drop("schoolId"); ??

Comment: can you paste the error message in the question ?

Comment: The method joinWith(Dataset<U>, Column) in the type Dataset<Student> is not applicable for the arguments (Dataset<School>, boolean)

Comment: Try `studentData.col("schoolId").equalTo(schoolDS.col("id"))` in your join. It should be `Column` expression in fact but you are comparing two objects.

Comment: Why do you convert your dataframe (Dataset<Row>) to datasets? It might be easier if you skip this step.